# SparseArray clone in Android

Tags: java, android, sparse-array

I am trying to iterate through a [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) and delete a few items.

> private SparseArray record;

```
   int size = record.size();
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++) {
            if (record.valueAt(index) < threshold){
                record.delete(record.keyAt(index));
            }
        }
```

But if I remove items midway through iteration, the size will change, So I cannot use this.
I tried to clone the sparse array beforehand. But eclipse gives me error

```
The method clone() from the type object is not visible
```

But both api doc and Source code of SparseArray indicate it is present and public.
Also the method clone has an annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Does suppressing change the visibility of method?
Anyone has a clue how to solve this or clone the SparseArray?

Comment: What version of Android are you developing for?

Comment: targetsdk is 15 and minsdk is 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Android API changes for SDK 14](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html), we find that [`SparseArray` was modified to include a `public` `clone`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes/android.util.SparseArray.html).

Edit

In my project, I implemented my own clone code for SB array: [Source code here](http://code.google.com/searchframe#y41LDfyHz_M/trunk/AndroidBindingV30/src/gueei/binding/v30/viewAttributes/absListView/Helper.java&q=SparseBooleanArray%20package%3aandroid-binding%5C.googlecode%5C.com)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, i changed the target, it shows up. I got confused by the Api doc which says its present since API level 1.

Comment: Well last time it took me 3 hours to figure that out as well.

Comment: There's an open ticket about the api docs being wrong. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39242

Comment: this link is not working , pls pick the code from below

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you get the size of the array like this? or just use size-- whenever you delete a record?

```
    for (int index = 0; index < record.size(); index++) {
        if (record.valueAt(index) < threshold){
            record.delete(record.keyAt(index));
            index--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: but the index would have been incremented by then, so it will skip one entry

Answer (score 2):

FYI in support-v4, SparseArrayCompat is available to address this issue and more:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/SparseArrayCompat.html

Answer (score 1):

`Clone` Method is protected for `Object` class so any class has to explicitly provide it but however I see this method in the documentation and Not in the source code. Seems that My `API Level` is `10` and docs `API level` is `16`. So please check your `API Level` first.

`@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is because `Clone` method of `Object` returns `Object` where as from doc it seems that it returns `SparseArray<E>` which results in unsafe cast inside method to convert `Object` to `SparseArray<E>`

Answer (score 1):

Still the clone is not updated in the API in Android docs nor it show any warning in compiling with API 9

So I wrote my own code for cloning the object

```
public static SparseBooleanArray getClone(SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
        return sparseBooleanArray.clone();
    return getCloneof(sparseBooleanArray);
}

private static SparseBooleanArray getCloneof(SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray) {

    SparseBooleanArray temp = new SparseBooleanArray();
    try {
        int[] mKeys;
        boolean[] mValues;
        int mSize;
        Field mKeysField = sparseBooleanArray.getClass().getDeclaredField("mKeys");
        Field mValuesField = sparseBooleanArray.getClass().getDeclaredField("mValues");
        Field mSizeField = sparseBooleanArray.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSize");

        mKeysField.setAccessible(true);
        mValuesField.setAccessible(true);
        mSizeField.setAccessible(true);

        mKeys = (int[]) mKeysField.get(sparseBooleanArray);
        mValues = (boolean[]) mValuesField.get(sparseBooleanArray);
        mSize = (int) mSizeField.getInt(sparseBooleanArray);

        Field mKeysFieldtemp = temp.getClass().getDeclaredField("mKeys");
        Field mValuesFieldtemp = temp.getClass().getDeclaredField("mValues");
        Field mSizeFieldtemp = temp.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSize");

        mKeysFieldtemp.setAccessible(true);
        mValuesFieldtemp.setAccessible(true);
        mSizeFieldtemp.setAccessible(true);

        mKeysFieldtemp.set(temp, mKeys);
        mValuesFieldtemp.set(temp, mValues);
        mSizeFieldtemp.setInt(temp, mSize);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}
```